# How do I install LMDB as backend in openLDAP?

Tags: centos7, openldap, lmdb

I have installed CentOS in the virtualbox. Now I want to install LDAP with LMDB as backend. When I've installed openLDAP, there was already a "olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif" file. Now I want to know how to change the database from HDB to LMDB.